# Sharepoint 2010 - Client Object Model - ContentTypeId keeps reverting back to original

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

first off: big fan of this site and have always found a solution to a problem when visiting here.
I have a small problem when using the *Client Object Model* for *Sharepoint 2010*:
I am trying to set the Content Type of an item, however it keeps reverting back to it's original `ContentTypeId` after I call the "`Context.ExecuteQuery()`".
Here is a sample of the code:

> ```
>     item["ContentTypeId"] = targetContentType.Id.ToString();
>     item.Update();
>     destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
> ```

If I step through the code and check the `ContentTypeId` I can that it has changed but as soon as I hit `ExecuteQuery` it reverts back to the original Content Type.
The item in question sits in a sub-folder of the document library and is a `docx` file. The Content Type itself does exist. If I run the same code on any other file type, e.g: `htm`; it changes the content type successfully.

Comment: Should it be just targetContentType.Id ??

Comment: Nope, .ToString() is correct as the type of item["Field"] is String. The code works for other items being inserted into the document library but just doesn't seem to like docx files for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can never change an content type id.(Similar to Column ID)

When you change the name of a content type, it's content type id will keep the same.

And you may check the content type id in the URL for the param ctype:

[image: http://bernadonguyenhoan.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/content-type-id.png]